# positive integer composite numbers $ n $ such that $ n $ divides $ 3 ^ {n-1} - 2 ^{n-1} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that exist infinite positive integer composite numbers $ n $ such that $ n $ divides $ 3 ^ {n-1} - 2 ^{n-1} $

Comment: **[I don't know if a comment is a right way to ask this, if not I apologize]** This exercise actually comes from a Telematic Selection Test for high school students for Italian Mathematical Olympiads which will end on December 30th ... is it possible to put the topic on hold until that date?

Comment: @wisefool The correct way is flagging the post for moderator attention, I believe. I have done it for you.

Comment: @wisefool Do you have a link? By our [Contest Questions policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) we can really only take action if we can verify that it _does_ come from such a source.